Short story involving time dilation and a girl growing up while her astronaut mother explores other planets
I am trying to find a short story I read a few years back in a science fiction course. I believe the name of it was "Borrowed Time" but there is a short film and a new anthology with the same title, so I can't find it online or the title is completely different.
The basic synopsis is a girl is growing up while her mother is an astronaut exploring other planets. Due to time dilation, whenever her mother visits she is basically the same age but the girl continues to grow. I remember the story ends with the mother dying because of an accident with falling rocks on another planet (I specifically remember the phrase "xenophobic stones" being used to describe it). The daughter is about 100 years old and dies shortly after the mother.
I read it in 2019 so it is older than that and I'm almost positive it was told in the first person.

Shore Leave Blacks by Nancy Etchemendy is similar in concept, though it's a son in it, not a daughter.

It seems to be quite a popular title with 8 exact matches in the past 20 years.  I didn't see any obvious matches there, though a number of them look to be extremely difficult to chase down.

You really remember my short story, "Borrowed Time" :)("Deuda temporal" in Spanish). Yes, it's a translation by Professor Daniel W. Koon for the compilation The ApexBook of World SF II edited by Lavie Tidhar. I'm glad to find a reader who pays so much attention to details. Did you locate it? You can find it at this link on Google Books. Thank you for being so interested in my little story.
https://books.google.com/books?id=K-WxS8n0RTMC&lpg=PA130&ots=y_umB0K39X&dq=anabel%20enr%C3%ADquez%20pi%C3%B1eiro&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=anabel%20enr%C3%ADquez%20pi%C3%B1eiro&f=false

@AnEnriWriter awesome that you're the author! :) Welcome to scifi.stackexchange!

@AnEnriWriter Thank you so much for taking the time to comment on my post! I first read your story in a freshman Sci-Fi class and I was preparing to defend my Master's thesis for astro/physics when I remembered it and I went a little crazy trying to remember where I read it so I'm extremely happy I was able to find it again and even that the author of one of my favorite short stories reached out.

So I followed DavidW's comment and went through the list, and I found it! It's Borrowed Time by Anabel Enríquez Piñeiro! It's a translation so that may be why it was so hard to find, thank you everyone for your assistance!

Your hair, a centimetre or two longer, your skin maybe more tanned than the last time. Smooth, yes, like a shiny shell, without a single fold, without a scar. Me, on the other hand, my face could serve as the canvas for an astronavigation map: you could catalogue all my wrinkles by latitude and longitude. And locate all its globular clusters, wormholes, and black holes. There's room for the entire universe on my face.

....

Look up above, so many worlds to visit, so many twilights beneath double and triple stars, the chance to use hyperjumps to effectively live forever…an eternity of journeying between the stars. I struggle in vain to understand your words, your passion for those faraway lights in unknown and unreachable houses that inhabit the night; I am only five years old.

....

One hundred and six years after your first departure, that message arrived on the hyperjump channel. That The Persephone would arrive in six days. That it would carry your body. Killed in an excavation accident on the fifth planet of Procyon Alpha. How large an error was it this time? One second, two...? Enough to bury all your passion for transcendence in an avalanche of xenophobic stones. I had wanted to cry, but at one hundred and eleven years of age, one's reflexes grow sluggish and sometimes disappear. I signed for your body in order to process the customary funeral ceremony. It did not surprise me to once again see the mother who had abandoned her home when I was five. Aside from the skin colour or the hair a centimetre or two longer, nothing had changed.


I'm pleased I was able to help, even just a little bit. :D  Don't forget to come back tomorrow and accept your answer!

Thank you for sending the answer! I was working hard to find it, not only to answer but because I wanted to read it. And any stories on time dilation, my favorite theme.

This is very close to Memories of My Mother by Ken Liu. This was published in 2012 and has been published in a number of places. The full text is available on the Daily Science Fiction web site here, so you can easily check if this is the story. It was adapted into a short file, but the film was called Beautiful Dreamer not Borrowed Time.
In the story the mother has an unidentified terminal disease that will kill her in two years. She uses the time dilation to stay alive long enough to see her daughter grow up, then age.
The story ends with the daughter enfeebled by old age. The mother doesn't die in the story, but her two years is up and she declares she will stay for good, with the implication being that she has chosen to stay and die with her daughter.
